# Chocolate numbers

Tags: code-golf, sequence, combinatorics

Given an `m` by `n` chocolate bar, `m,n` positive, output the number of ways to break the bar into `mn` 1 by 1 pieces where each break occurs on a gridline.

Order is important. Pieces are also distinguishable, so the two pieces on either end of a 1 by 3 chocolate bar are not equivalent.

For instance, for a 2 by 2 block we have:

```
 _ _            _   _            _   _            _   _
|_‖_|    ->    |‗| |_|    ->    |_| |‗|    ->    |_| |_|
|_‖_|          |_| |_|           _  |_|           _   _
                                |_|              |_| |_|


 _ _            _   _            _   _            _   _
|_‖_|    ->    |_| |‗|    ->    |‗| |_|    ->    |_| |_|
|_‖_|          |_| |_|          |_|  _            _   _
                                    |_|          |_| |_|


 _ _            _ _              _   _            _   _
|‗|‗|    ->    |_‖_|      ->    |_| |_|    ->    |_| |_|
|_|_|           _ _               _ _             _   _
               |_|_|             |_‖_|           |_| |_|


 _ _            _ _               _ _             _   _
|‗|‗|    ->    |_|_|      ->     |_‖_|    ->     |_| |_|
|_|_|           _ _              _   _            _   _
               |_‖_|            |_| |_|          |_| |_|
```

Hence there are 4 ways to break up a 2 by 2 chocolate bar.

#### Rules

- Input will be two integers via function input, STDIN, command line or similar. Output a single number, the number of ways to break up the chocolate bar.
- Since the numbers go up pretty quickly, don't worry if the output exceeds the integer limits of your language – your submission will be valid as long as the algorithm theoretically works for all possible inputs.

#### Test cases

The output doesn't depend on the order of `m,n`, so the test cases are listed such that `m <= n`.

```
1 1 -> 1
1 2 -> 1
1 3 -> 2
1 4 -> 6
1 5 -> 24
1 10 -> 362880

2 2 -> 4
2 3 -> 56
2 4 -> 1712
2 5 -> 92800
2 10 -> 11106033743298560

3 3 -> 9408
3 4 -> 4948992
3 5 -> 6085088256
3 10 -> 76209753666310470268511846400

4 4 -> 63352393728
```

[A261964](https://oeis.org/A261964) is the chocolate numbers arranged in a triangle such that each row corresponds to the sum `m+n`.

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica, 85 bytes

```
f=If[##==1,1,Tr[Sum[Binomial[1##-2,i#-1]f[i,#]f[#2-i,#],{i,#2-1}]&@@@{{##},{#2,#}}]]&
```

**Test case**

```
f[4,4]
(* 63352393728 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>168</s>, <s>156</s>, 147 bytes

Made improvements thanks to chat

```
f=lambda n:n<1or n*f(n-1);a=lambda m,n,c=lambda m,n:sum(f(m*n-2)/f(i*n-1)/f((m-i)*n-1)*a(i,n)*a(m-i,n)for i in range(1,m)):+(m+n<4)or c(m,n)+c(n,m)
```

Ungolfed:

```
f=lambda n:n<1or n*f(n-1) # Factorial
def a(m, n):
    if m+n < 4:
        return 1
    first = 0
    for i in range(1,m):
        first += f(m*n-2) * 1/f(i*n-1) * 1/f((m-i)*n-1) * a(i,n) * a(m-i,n)
    second = 0
    for i in range(1,n):
        second += f(m*n-2) * 1/f(i*m-1) * 1/f((n-i)*m-1) * a(i,m) * a(n-i,m)
    return first + second
```

Algorithm was based on [this paper](http://www.emis.de/journals/JIS/VOL19/Khovanova/khova9.pdf).

I could probably cut it down a lot more, I'm just not sure where

Answer (score 3):

## R, <s>208</s> 198 bytes

```
f=function(m,n){g=function(i,j){a=0;if(j>1)for(x in 2:j-1)a=a+choose(j*i-2,x*i-1)*M[x,i]*M[j-x,i];a};s=max(m,n);M=matrix(1,s,s);for(i in 1:s)for(j in 1:s)if(i*j>2)M[i,j]=M[j,i]=g(i,j)+g(j,i);M[m,n]}
```

Indented, with newlines:

```
f = function(m,n){
    g=function(i,j){
        a = 0
        if(j>1) for(x in 2:j-1) a = a + choose(j*i-2,x*i-1) * M[x,i] * M[j-x,i]
        a
    }
    s = max(m,n)
    M = matrix(1,s,s)
    for(i in 1:s) for(j in 1:s) if(i*j>2) M[i,j] = M[j,i] = g(i,j) + g(j,i)
    M[m,n]
}
```

Usage:

```
> f(3,1)
[1] 2
> f(3,2)
[1] 56
> f(3,3)
[1] 9408
> f(4,3)
[1] 4948992
> f(5,3)
[1] 6085088256
```

Comment: In theory, one can write a shorter recursive version of ca. 160 bytes but it quickly reaches the default recursion limit and the default protection stack size and modifying these defaults (respectively using `options(expressions=...)` and argument `--max-ppsize=`) would result in a longer code than this one.

Comment: You can save two bytes by omitting `f=`.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 135 bytes

```python
C=lambda A:sum(C(A[:i]+A[i+1:]+[(c,H),(W-c,H)])for i,Q in enumerate(A)for W,H in(Q,Q[::-1])for c in range(1,W))or 1
print C([input()])
```

Here's what I came up with. It's really slow, but here's a faster version (needs [repoze.lru](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/repoze.lru/0.6)):

```python
from repoze.lru import lru_cache
C=lru_cache(maxsize=9999)(lambda A:sum(C(tuple(sorted(A[:i]+A[i+1:]+((c,H),(W-c,H)))))for i,Q in enumerate(A)for W,H in(Q,Q[::-1])for c in range(1,W))or 1)
print C((input(),))
```

#### Examples

```
$ time python2 chocolate.py <<< 2,5
92800

real    0m2.954s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.015s

$ time python2 chocolate-fast.py <<< 3,5
6085088256

real    0m0.106s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.015s
```

#### Explanation

The code defines a function `C` that takes an array of pieces. The algorithm is as such:

1. `for i,Q in enumerate(A)`: loop through the array of pieces.
2. `for W,H in(Q,Q[::-1])`: calculate ways twice, rotating 90 degrees.
3. `for c in range(1,W)`: loop through possible positions to split at.
4. `A[:i]+A[i+1:]+[(c,H),(W-c,H)]`: get a list without the split piece and with the two new pieces.
5. `C(…)`: call the function again on that list.
6. `sum(…)`: sum the results for each possible split.
7. `or 1`: if no splits are possible, there is exactly one way to split the chocolate.

Finally, the code is called with an array containing the input.

Answer (score 1):

### ES6, 141 bytes

```
c=(m,n)=>(f=n=>n<2||n*f(n-1),h=(m,n)=>[...Array(m-1)].reduce((t,_,i)=>t+f(m*n-2)/f(++i*n-1)/f((m-i)*n-1)*c(i,n)*c(m-i,n),0),h(m,n)+h(n,m))||1
```

Based on the formula found by @CameronAavik. Ungolfed:

```
function fact(n) {
    return n < 2 ? 1 : n * f(n - 1);
}
function half(m, n) {
    total = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < m; i++)
        total += fact(m * n - 2) / fact(i * n - 1) / fact((m - i) * n - 1) * choc(i, n) * choc(m - i, n)
    return total;
}
function choc(m, n) {
    total = half(m, n) + half(n, m);
    if (!total) total = 1;
    return total;
}
```